# NAND and NOT operators

Tags: syntax, verilog

I would like to convert the following into `NAND` and `NOT` gates only in Verilog HDL.

```
A & B | C
```

I tried the following in Verilog:

```
A &~ B &~ ~C
```

However, I get a syntax error at token `~` in the `~C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
~(~(A&B) & ~C)
```